# AEHD 2.1 (Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver) for Intel processor is not available in Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Android developer documentation claims that AEHD 2.1 will replace HAXM in AS Flamingo

> On Intel Processors, the Android Emulator hypervisor driver can be installed via the SDK Manager in Android Studio Flamingo or later.

It looks that nothing has been changed and I need to proceed with HAXM.
Am I correct?

[Configure VM acceleration using Android Emulator hypervisor driver (AEHD) on Windows](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-aehd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be able to install and use AEHD 2.0. BTW: there is no functional change between 2.1 and 2.0.

I think the doc just says HAXM will be replaced by AEHD; it does not *have* to be AEHD 2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cannot understand when HAXM is considered to be obsolete and 
should be replaced with AEHD 2.x. Emulator configuration documentation claims that: 
a)for Emulator 32.x.x.x I should proceed with HAXM for Intel processor.
b)can switch to AEHD 2.1 starting from AS Flamingo or later.
AS Flamingo is deployed with Emulator 32.x.x.x

Comment: Great question. This can be misleading indeed when the emulator is treated as a part of Android Studio. It used to be somehow separated (for example, HAXM is installed via SDK manager the same way as the emulator but probably no one thinks it is part of the studio). Android Studio used to allow users to choose among stable/beta/canary emulators. If users have multiple Android Studio installed sharing the same SDK_ROOT, the Studio Flamingo can be working with emulator > 32.x.x.x. For b) you mentioned, the doc actually means that Studio Flamingo can install AEHD on Intel platforms.

Comment: Have to separate the comments due to word limit. Older Android Studio ( before Flamingo) can only install AEHD on AMD platforms. At that time, AEHD was still called "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" and the short name was GVM. You should choose between HAXM and AEHD based on the emulator version just as a) you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your time. According to AEHD release notes: a)"AEHD for AMD Processors" was renamed to AEHD in v2.0 b)GVM was renamed to AEHD in v2.1. As fas as I remember AEHD 2.0 was available in AS EE. Guess emulator team was planning to release 33.x.x.x with AS Flamingo, modified docs but 
emulator 33 release was delayed.